# Dropdown Menu on hover image

Tags: html, css

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_dropdowns.asp)

Hello,

I've been trying to integrate a drop down menu based upon the hover over function of an image. I've gone to the above website which gives an example, but I cannot figure it out. Below is my current HTML. The image I would like to have the hover over function work on and from that have a drop down menu is the Logo.png file. I simply cannot figure out how to integrate this into my code. Any direction or help would be appreciated.

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #808080;
}
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 140px;
  background-color: #555555;
}
#logopic {
  height: 100px;
  width: 140px;
}
#logo {
  float: left;
  margin: 1%;
  width: 160px;
}
.menuoptions {
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 14px;
  float: left;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 45px;
  font-size: 125%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.menuoptions:hover {
  color: #00b9f1;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
#topsection {
  padding-top: 150px;
}
ul li {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">

  <div id="logodiv">
    <a href="index.html">
      <img id="logo" src="images/Logo.png">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="menulinks">

    <ul id="options">
      <a href="#income">
        <li class="menuoptions">INCOME</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#expenses">
        <li class="menuoptions">EXPENSES</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#incomedistribution">
        <li class="menuoptions">INCOME DISTRIBUTION</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#spending">
        <li class="menuoptions">SPENDING</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#sidemenu">
        <li class="menuoptions">SIDE MENU</li>
      </a>
    </ul>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: u want open menu on hover image ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the sibligns selector "+"

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #808080;
}
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 140px;
  background-color: #555555;
}
#logopic {
  height: 100px;
  width: 140px;
}
#logo {
  float: left;
  margin: 1%;
  width: 160px;
}
.menuoptions {
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 14px;
  float: left;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 45px;
  font-size: 125%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.menuoptions:hover {
  color: #00b9f1;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
#topsection {
  padding-top: 150px;
}
ul li {
  list-style-position: inside;
}

#menulinks {
  display: none;
}

#logodiv:hover + #menulinks {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">

  <div id="logodiv">
    <a href="index.html">
      <img id="logo" src="images/Logo.png">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="menulinks">

    <ul id="options">
      <a href="#income">
        <li class="menuoptions">INCOME</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#expenses">
        <li class="menuoptions">EXPENSES</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#incomedistribution">
        <li class="menuoptions">INCOME DISTRIBUTION</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#spending">
        <li class="menuoptions">SPENDING</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#sidemenu">
        <li class="menuoptions">SIDE MENU</li>
      </a>
    </ul>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Germano Plebani > I believe it won't work, because when you stop hovering the logo, the menu will disappear again.

I changed your code a bit to make it a bit more simple (at least, in my opinion) :

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
    <li id="logo"><img src="your_path"></li>
    <li class="menuoptions">INCOME</li>
    <li class="menuoptions">EXPENSES</li>
    <li class="menuoptions">INCOME DISTRIBUTION</li>
    <li class="menuoptions">SPENDING</li>
    <li class="menuoptions">SIDE MENU</li>
</ul>
```

```
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #808080;
}
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 140px;
  background-color: #555555;
}
#logo {
  height:140px;
}

#logo img{
  width:160px;
}
ul{
  height:inherit;
  width:160px; /* Your menu has the size of your logo */
}

ul:hover {
  width:auto; /* when you hover your menu, it will take 100% of the width of it's container */
}
ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style:none;
}
ul:hover .menuoptions {
  display:block;
}
.menuoptions {
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 45px;
  font-size: 125%;
  font-weight: bold;
  display:none;
}
.menuoptions:hover {
  color: #00b9f1;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

I didn't go for optimization neither, but it works fine.